# How do I configure a stretch cluster without shared storage between two sites?

Tags: storage, disaster-recovery, windows-server-2016

I am trying to redesign our IT infrastructure and seeking help in implementing DR solution for our company.

I see that as 2 data centers in active-passive mode with the data replication. Currently we have two Windows Servers 2016 at the primary site and a single Windows server at DR location.

Between the sites we have 1Gb network connection, but I'm not sure about the latency though. So I am just wondering if it would be possible to configure some kind of storage replication to ensure the data is available to these 2 sites?

Now I am leaning towards a stretch cluster with the Storage Replica, but looks like I need to acquire an additional node for my DR site to implement that.

So could someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an article where you can learn more about the main idea behind Storage Replica, all its prerequisites and features: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/storage/storage-replica/storage-replica-overview

And here you can find the guide on how to implement volume replication with stretched cluster: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/how-to-configure-storage-replication-using-windows-server-2016-part-2

Please note that you need Datacenter licencies to get started with Storage replica.

Comment: Thank you mate for your help. Job is already done. I didnt put the cluster in production yet, but I like what I'm seeing so far.